# UIImageView image not showing up

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

```
_topBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];

UIImageView *bar = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar.png"]];
bar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45);
[_topBar addSubview:bar];

_up = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"]];
[_topBar addSubview:_up];
```

_up does not show up in my build. If i exchange the "up.png" for any other image in my resources folder, it shows up, but up.png refuses to. Is there anything I can do? I've initialized it using just a UIImage, a statically allocated UIImageView, removed and re-added the .png files, took them out of the resources folder and put them somewhere else, re-saved them, everything aside from throwing them out.

**EDIT:**
  The file was saved as up.png but was really up.png.psd. just a matter of reading the fine print.

Comment: If you right click on the image in Finder and Get Info, What is listed under Kind?

Comment: ...adobe photoshop file. thank you sir, i saved it as a up.png but never actually changed it to a png.

Comment: Put up an answer to go along with the comment. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the Kind in Finder. Its probably not a png and therefore wouldn't display.

I now know this to be true since you commented :)

Comment: I was skeptical of this answer because my UIImageView had been working fine for about a week and then randomly just didn't show anymore.

Sure enough it was a JPG and not PNG. Weird that it worked at all.

Comment: Not really that weird, `UIImage` reads from binary data and it doesn't really care about filename at all. First few bytes in the header would be good enough to determine if it's a valid image file or not.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things. Select the file in the right pane, open the rightmost (3rd) file inspector pane, and insure that this image is included in your Target.

In code, break out this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"];
NSLog(@"image %@", image);
_up = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"]];
NSLog(@"UP FRAME: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_up.frame) );
// maybe set the frame to what you want?
_up.frame = (CGRect){ {0,0}, image.size }; // set origin where you want it
```