# UIImageView not showing on iOS6

Tags: ios, uiimageview

in ios5 i implemented my UIImageView like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstScreen.png"]];

imageView.frame =  CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,[GeneralUtils screenWidth],[GeneralUtils screenHeight]);

// !!!!!!!!!!!!!
[self.view addSubview: imageView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.tableView];
```

Everything´s fine...But now in ios6 my UIImageView is not showing anymore....

Comment: Please explain why you have the code moving stuff to the back. (Or show all the code).

Comment: there are two things that you should take care of..
1. Hight & Width of your GeneralUtils Shouldn't be zero.
2. May be, your ImageView going underneath to some other view.
other wise this code seems correct and should work perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by setting

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundView: nil];
```

I think my tableView was hiding the Image!

Answer (score 1):

try bellow code..

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstScreen.png"]];

imageView.frame =  screenBounds;

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: what you want ?? i think you want to display image on front of the screen right??

Comment: exactly! i want an image as background of my View!

Comment: @chrizstone in ios 6 its required some perfact word and type of files... so first check that you have FirstScreen.png available in finder or not.. and also check the type... :)

Comment: Yes it is available and the type is correct! If i try it with ios5 Simulator every things good...

Comment: @chrizstone just try with add new .png file in your project directory from finder and then try to use it here and then let me know.. in simulator and in Device you can see many difference so always try to test also in Device... :)

Comment: now i search about that same issue and i find this link which answer same like my answer just see dude.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043589/uiimageview-image-not-showing-up :)

Comment: in that answer what he wrongs is this **The file was saved as up.png but was really up.png.psd. just a matter of reading the fine print.**

Comment: Yes, i know those issues...But my File is definitely a PNG File...Why would it be shown on iOS 5 though?!

Comment: oh ok now just create same image with size of 320 * 580 and save as a **FirstScreen@2x.png**

Comment: main 3 types of image and try with these three For example... ** Default.png,Default-568h@2x.png,Default@2x.png** just try with different way bcoz now i think these is the problem.. only one...

Comment: Nah, same! But i saw another strange log in my output window! If i start my app on ios5 Simulator, nothing is in the Output! But on ios6, i get Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Comment: @chrizstone also reset the simulator from **iOS Simulator => Reset content and settings**